# How to pass a user input into a command line application via the command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, password, input

I have a command line application which requires a user input:

```
./some_application

# something happens here.....
# something happens here too.....

Enter secret pass phrase:
```

I want to call it from a terminal and pass a secret pass phrase to it right away, without having to enter it manually. How can I do that? I've tried this but it didn't work and I still was asked to provide secret pass phrase:

```
./some_application my_secret_pass_phrase
```

Comment: use `expect` https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: You should know that your "secret pass phrase" that you pass as a command line argument will be saved in your shell history, will be visible in the process table while your application is running, and thus *won't be secret anymore.*

Comment: How did you try it exactly? What language is your application written in? Did you try googling for "commandline arguments language X" where "language X" is whatever you used to write your application?

Comment: STDIN is not the same as command-line arguments. You're confusing the two - you're trying to pass off a command-line argument as STDIN, which won't work. Instead of "command line user input" (which will come back as command-line arguments), try searching for something like "pass argument to STDIN".

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- what are you actually trying to do? What is "some application"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
printf '%s\n' 'password' | ./some_program
```

Or use `expect`, as Ipor Sircer [advised in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325134/how-to-pass-a-user-input-into-a-command-line-application-via-the-command-line-ar#comment572009_325134).